# Unable to parse configuration of MapStruct plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, mapstruct

I was recently adding a MapStruct as a dependency to my project but I have run into issue with adding MapStruct as a dependency into project .pom file and congiguring it.

Here is my .pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.opensourcedev</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ticket-manager</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artefactId>mapstruct-processor</artefactId>
                            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After I hit *clean* and *compile* I get error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ticket-manager: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile for parameter artefactId: Cannot find 'artefactId' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.DependencyCoordinate
```

I don't quite understand what is the problem here but I can guess that the  is not processed or is misplaced, i don't know.
I have used MapStruct in my previous projects but this is the first time I have encountered this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MapStruct.

You have a typo in your configuration.

Instead of `artifactId` you have `artefactId`. Notice the `e` after the `art`.

Comment: What a fool I am. I didn't see this typo. But I will take a loot at it since I have edited this .pom file many times maybe this isn't causing the problem.
So I will fix the typo, hit "clean", "compile" and report back